# Changing the image in an Android compound TextView - not working

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable

OK people, I'm going seriously nuts here. That late night stuff when you've tried everything...

I've got a compound TextView with an image on the left. The image (a little pic that just says "loading") is set with:

```
Drawable img = getBaseContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.loading );
img.setBounds( 0, 0, 120, 120 );
tv.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );
```

tv is the TextView variable. That works fine. However, later I want to replace the image with a new drawable, I've tried to call setCompoundDrawables again:

```
tv.setCompoundDrawables( new_img, null, null, null );
```

I've also tried getting the array of drawables for the TextView and replacing the left one, as shown here:

```
Drawable[] drw = tv.getCompoundDrawables();
drw[0] = new_img;
```

The code runs ok in debug mode. No exceptions occur. All UI handling performed within the UI thread. Images seem to be ok, etc, but the display does not change. Do I have to refresh the display in some way?

By the way, the TextViews are added within a vertical LinearLayout if that matters. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here but I can't see it. Many thanks in advance.

(Yes, I know I could replace my design with an ImageView and a vanilla TextView, however for performance reasons I'd prefer to stick with a Compound TextView if possible)

Comment: You can use a list view with custom adapter and use lazy loading for displaying images. That way it would be less complex from your side.

Comment: The second approach I would not expect to work properly, at least without `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()`. The first approach I would have expected to work, by eyeballing the `TextView` source code (I've never tried changing these myself...). You could try calling `setCompoundDrawables()` with four `null` values, then your `setCompoundDrawables()` with the new image. In principle, the four-`null`s would return you to your original state, in which case the new `setCompoundDrawables()` should work as well as your original one did.

Comment: Many thanks guys. I'm not familiar with lazy loading so will look that up. Also, the custom adapter sounds worth a go.

Answer (score 4):

setCompoundDrawables() is unable to decode the bounding box for drawables. 
Instead, use [TextView::setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) for using the implicit bounds for the drawable. This will ensure better handling across different screen densities.

Answer (score 2):

OK. I got this to work, but Android seemed to be very picky about how it will work. I'm posting the answer in case it helps other people.

Here's the code that worked. Nothing special, until you read the comments below showing what other methods didn't work.

```
// resize the images. these methods seem to be very particular about how the bounds are set
img.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, 120, 120));    // it likes this
tvp.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );  // this works for sure when combined with setBounds(Rect)

// what didn't work... (would have to more experimenting with what works and what doesn't)
//img.setBounds( 0, 0, 240, 240 ); // it didn't like this!

//Drawable[] drw = tvp.getCompoundDrawables();
//drw[0] = img;     // it didn't like this technique of assigning a new image

//tvp.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(img, null, null, null);   // no good, as it uses original (intrinsic) size of the image
//tvp.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(img, null, null, null);  // doesn't like this - nothing bad happens; it just doesn't change the image
```

Hope this helps someone. Cheers, Tom